# "magento2/sitemap.xml" is always and automatically added to my robots.txt

Tags: magento2, sitemaps, robots.txt

I don't know how and why I find the following in my robots.txt

```
Sitemap: http://www.[mySite].com/magento2/sitemap.xml
```

worse the link opens to a "404 page not found".

I have tried to remove it from my robots.txt (under Stores\General\General\Design) but just the next day and I can see it down at the end of my `http://www.[mySite].com/sitemap.xml`

Note that at the top of my `http://www.[mySite].com/magento2/sitemap.xml` there is a correct link to my sitemap.

How can I remove that permanently?

Answer (score 2):

you have to set this option to Enable Submission to Robots.txt to  **NO**

[image]

hope this will work for you

Comment: I don't want to disable the whole robots.txt !!! ... I just want to remove that extra automatically added sitemap link

Comment: it will disable robots.txt, it is just to stop append your sitemap.xml path to this file

Comment: @Whaaaaat, don't forget to accept this answer, so some one can use it in future and it will help them

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code in your
app/design/frontend/Company_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Sitemap/layout/robots_index_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="sitemapRobotsLinks" remove="true"/>
```